# How to display cross-references between multiple volumes?

Tags: book

I am preparing a book which is too lengthy to appear as a single volume. The format is similar to an encyclopedia. It has many cross-references, e.g. "see Bears, p. 20". What is the typical way to have page numbers and cross-references in multi-volume works? And do page numbers in the second volume typically continue where the first volume ended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paraphrased from the *Chicago Manual of Style* (15th edition; section 1.105 - Separate versus consecutive pagination): the decision for whether page numbering continues or begins anew in a subsequent volume rests with the publisher. They recommend that a publication with two volumes with a combined index at the end of the second volume would be easier with continued page numbering, but that as the number of volumes increase beyond two, or where page numbers run in more than three digits, consider resetting the page number to 1 for each volume.

With respect to the format of the cross-reference, including the volume number is preferred for ease of use, whether pages are numbered in a continuous manner or whether they restart with each volume. Generally, the format would be something like `(see bears, 2:117)` where the `2` represents the volume number and `117` represents the page number in that volume.